# Extract only number/numeric

Tags: sql, regex, amazon-redshift

I have URL which is received by the application. The URL can take any format, but it always has a number at the end.

For example -

```
/Page/Modern-Day-Hotel-59460
/Page/Future-Fun-Days-At-Beach-223345
/Page/Hello-Page-123
/Page/This-Page/Second-Page/Main-Product-44231
```

As you can see there is a numeric value at the end of URL. I'm trying to extract only the numeric portion of the URL. is there any way to achieve this ? Since the URL length will change and the number size also varies, I'm looking for something generic

I'm using amazon redshift database

Comment: Does redshift support `regexp_replace()`?

Comment: If you are looking for the regexp then it is `'\d+$'`. Using PostgreSQL it could be `substring(<value> from '\d+$')` (here `\d+` - any non-empty sequence of digits and `$` is the end of the line)

Answer (score 0):

If the number is always preceded by a hyphen (as in your examples), relatively simple string manipulation is sufficient:

```
select right(col, position('-' in reverse(col)) - 1)
```

Note that this returns the last string after the last hyphen.  It does not check that it is a number.